# How to get ClassLabel for the ai4privacy/pii-masking-200k dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I am working on fine tuning of the NER Model. For this, I have downloaded the dataset as shown in the below image:

[image]

If you take a look at features of this dataset, there isn't "ner_tags" which has ClassLabel. How do we get the ClassLabel from this dataset?

For reference, below is the image of the ClassLabel from the connllpp dataset. I'm looking for something similar!

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!